# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Level

Tags: java

I am trying to run RestClient .From this code I deleted all Loggers related code.But I kept classpath for log4j same. Then run the application ,it gives following two exceptions

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Level
       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Level

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Level
```

Please give reason for those exceptions.

Comment: It will be difficult to respond to this without more details; you seem to have left a reference to log4j somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Other jars that you use most likely will use log4j.  Also, make sure you remove imports of log4j, not just the code that uses it.